# Cross origin request from web client to API server

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, angular-resource

I have a website made with AngularJS. This website makes API calls to an API server that lives in a sub directory on the same domain. The calls from my AngularJS code to the API only work when I visit my web page with `www` in URL.

Because my AngularJS app calls all the API's with the `www` subdomain in the URL as well.

When I visit my page like so: `http://example.com`, then all calls to `http://www.example.com/api/Something` fail because of Cross Domain policy.

People simply sometimes go to `http://example.com` and others use `www.example.com`. So what is the best practice to solve this problem in an AngularJS application that makes API calls through `$resource`?

---

Fixed it by adding this header to PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: @MatthewGreen Are you sure? Isn't it normal that making requests from `http://domain` to `http://www.domain` are considered cross domain requests?

Comment: @MatthewGreen You're right. I fixed this by adding a header to my server response. Could you add that as an answer so I have something to accept.

Comment: Done. You may want to update the answer or add your own though that shows what header you added since that could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to handle this in your code, I would make sure your server is handling calls to either URL as the same that way you aren't dealing with the switching back and forth. That should eliminate any issues with CORS.